# How can we add taxonomy as a base slug to custom post in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I want to add category as a base slug. for example.

https://example.com/category_name/post_name

Like this.

I tried below code. but after applying this solution my all pages & posts are going to 404. what can i do?

```
function wpa_course_post_link( $post_link, $id = 0 ){
$post = get_post($id);  
if ( is_object( $post ) ){
    $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'landing-category' );
    if( $terms ){
        return str_replace( '%landing-category%' , $terms[0]->slug , $post_link );
    }
}
return $post_link;
```

}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'wpa_course_post_link', 1, 3 );

Comment: As an alternative, have you tried a custom permalink structure in Settings -> Permalinks like the following? /`%category%`/`%postname%`